# GNU make in newly created subdirectory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

First - I know there are a lot of discussions similar to this, but I've spent hours without them working for me.

My makefile first creates a directory named by the current date and time. I then have the makefile append to a header file a line which creates a string with this directory name. For this reason, I first need to copy all the source files (including the header) into the newly created subdirectory, so that I can preserve the original header and only modify the header (in the subdirectory) which will be used for compilation. I would then like to build in that new directory.

My trouble is getting make to properly build the `.o` files in the new subdirectory. The solution I've found is to have

`$(NOW)%.o: $(NOW)%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) $<`

where `$(NOW)$` is the subdirectory name. The issue is that my `$(FLAGS)` seem to be ignored: the output is, roughly

`g++   -c -o <.o file> <.cpp file>`

(Yes, there is actually extra introduced space between `g++` and `-c`.) Whereas building in the top level directory a la

`%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) $<`

correctly outputs

`g++ -c <my flags> -o <.o file> <.cpp file>`

To summarize, I am unable to compile normally by transferring the source files to a newly-created subdirectory and building the `.o` files in that directory. TYIA.

Comment: Post the line where `$(FLAGS)` is set.   If it is a target-specific variable, then that could lead to the problem you're describing.   Also, if it is set using `:=` and is _below_ the `$(NOW)%.o` target, then its value will not take effect in that rule.   A more complete makefile would definately help in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Ad John points out, there's no way to definitively diagnose your problem with the tiny bit of makefile you provided, because the error is not in the code you provided, it's in some other part of your makefile.  You need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ideally, but if not that then at least we need to see how the `NOW` variable is set and the linker rule so we know what make is trying to build.

I should also point out that by convention you should not use `CC` to hold the C++ compiler; the `CC` variable holds the C compiler.  Use `CXX` for the C++ compiler and `CXXFLAGS` for the C++ compiler flags.

One possibility is that you are assigning the `NOW` variable using a recursive assignment so that the timestamp is recreated every time the variable is evaluated; it could be that the timestamp changes over the lifetime of the makefile.

The other very common problem is that you created the pattern rule, but make is not using it because the targets make wants to build don't match the pattern.

So for example, if your link line looks like this:

```
SRCS = foo.cpp
OBJS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

myprog: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) ...

$(NOW)%.o : $(NOW)%.cpp
        $(CXX) ...
```

then your pattern will not be matched because make is trying to build the file `foo.o` and your rule tells it how to build `$(NOW)foo.o` which are not the same thing.